# How to change the view when tap the sign in button?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
@State private var email = ""
@State private var password = ""
@EnvironmentObject var session:SessionStore
@EnvironmentObject var viewRouter:ViewRouter

func signIn(email: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
    if let error = error {
        self.error = error.localizedDescription}
    else {
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""
    }
}


var body: some View {
    
    if (error != "") {
        Text(error)
    }
    
    Button(action: {
        signIn()
        viewRouter.currentPage = .entrypage
        
    }, label: {
        Text("Sign In")
    })
    
}
```

When I tap Sign in button view change no matter if email and password are empty.
I want to make condition when email or password are empty to show error and otherwise to sign in and change the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions. Here is one:
You could use a ternary operator on your button like this to prevent the button to be used if there is no email/password present:
.disabled(self.email == "" || self.password ==  "")

Edited answer in response to your comment:

```
Button(action: {
    if self.email == "" || self.password ==  "" {
       self.error = "Please enter your credentials first."
    }
    else {
       signIn()
       viewRouter.currentPage = .entrypage
    }
    
}, label: {
    Text("Sign In")
})
```

Comment: Didn't help me much cause i need to press button to see if there is an error.  @Kuhlemann

Comment: See my edited answer. If it helped, please be so kind and mark your question as solved.